# С#: вопрос по сокетам

Tags: c#, сокет, сеть

Есть код сокета:

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); //Создаем основной сокет
IPAddress ipAddress = null; //IP-адресс
IPEndPoint Addr = null; //конечная точка(IP и порт)

Console.WriteLine("1 - Server\n2 - Client");
switch (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar)
{
    case '1':
        Console.Title = "Server"; //Сервер
        //ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0]; //Преобразовуем адрес или IP узла в массив IP и берем первый
        Addr = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5300); //"localhost" = 127.0.0.1
        s.Bind(Addr); //"Адресуем" сокет
        s.Listen(10); //Обозначаем количество ожидающих в очереди на подключение
        Console.WriteLine("Ждем коннекта...");
        Socket cl_s = s.Accept(); //Ожидаем подключения
        Console.WriteLine("Есть коннект!");
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable) //Пока не нажата клавиша
        {
            byte[] msg = new byte[cl_s.Available];
            cl_s.Receive(msg); //Принимаем МСГ
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg)); //Конвертируем и выводим
        }
        cl_s.Close(); //Закрываем сокет
        break;
    case '2':
        Console.Title = "Client"; //Клиент
        ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
        Addr = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 5300); //"localhost" = 127.0.0.1
        s.Connect(Addr); //Коннектимся к серверу
        while (true) //Вечная истина :)
        {
            byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine()); //Конвертируем
            s.Send(msg); //Отправляем
        }
        break;
}
s.Close(); //Закрываем сокет
Console.ReadKey();
```

В принципе все понятно: клиент отсылает, сервер принимает сообщения.

Я хочу научиться делать такую вещь: **клиент отправил сообщение - ждет сервера - ответ пришел - потом прочитал ответ**. Потом заново отправил сообщение и пр. Т.е. обычный сокет, но не понимаю как его сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле весь необходимый код у вас уже есть. Сейчас у вас сервер только принимает данные в цикле `while`, а клиент только отправляет. Для того, чтобы они обменивались сообщениями просто чередуйте в циклах приёма-передачи команды `Send` и `Receive`.

Команда `Receive`, если нет данных, ждёт, пока они не придут, так что заботиться о синхронизации отправки и приёма вам на этом уровне не нужно. Можно также задать значение тайм-аута `ReceiveTimeout`. Если данные не придут в течение этого времени, то возникнет исключение `SocketException`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Т.е., чтобы клиент получал ответ, нужно после s.Send(msg); дописать  var res = s.Receive() ? а если будет сбой (как вариант) и ответ придет не полностью? (я так понимаю, программа его распознать не сможет, т.к. он не полный, то это ошибка будет?)

Comment: Зависит от вида сбоя. Часть ошибок отлавливается протоколами более низкого уровня. Например, если пакеты не в том порядке пришли, или по проводу не тот бит пришёл. Сокеты предоставляют надёжный (в пределах разумного) канал передачи данных.
А вот если сбой был в клиенте, и он, скажем, завершился до того, как передал всё, что хотел, то это нужно отлавливать самому. В данном случае как раз и помогают тайм-ауты.
Вообще, если планируется более-менее сложная передача данных, то нужно хорошо продумать протокол или выбрать уже готовый, который подходит для задачи.

Comment: Если вы просто хотите разобраться с сокетами, то в качестве простого примера можете попробовать сделать маленький веб-сервер, который на любой запрос выдаёт какой-то текст. Протокол HTTP довольно простой. А потом добавьте новые возможности.

Comment: спасибо, попробую.

Comment: а какие есть уже готовые  протоколы?

Comment: Протоколов очень много. Например, в .NET уже есть встроенная поддержка упоминавшегося HTTP. С его помощью можно реализовать так называемую [архитектуру REST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST). Если хотите что-то более высокоуровневое для обмена данными, то можете использовать [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`cl_s.Accept` делайте в глобальном цикле или в отдельном потоке  (если планируется работать с несколькими клиентами одновременно).

`cl_s.Receive` в другом цикле/потоке. Загружайте до тех пор пока свойство Available не станет 0, или передавайте первый `byte`/`short`/`int`/`bigint` в качестве значения длины сообщения, и повторяйте до тех пор пока не получите все сообщение. Если клиент неожиданно разорвет соединение выскочит либо exception, либо передаст 0 байт. В этом случае, просто выходим из цикла (обробатываем искл. ситуацию).

После получения полного сообщения можно заняться его обработкой.
В этом плане лучше(удобнее) использовать класс `TcpListener`, `TcpClient`. Они значительно упрощают взаимодействие клиента/сервера.

HTTP-конечно прост, но в данном случае будет избыточен. Только в пустую потратите время.

Comment: Да, пожалуйста, только не забывайте ставить вопрос решен, на том ответе, который Вас удовлетворил больше.
Еще не много добавлю. Что если собираетесь делать свой протокол, то лучше использовать вариант с длиной сообщения в первых байтах. Так безопасней. Иначе находите в интернетах самый простой HTTP-сервер + Сериализация/Десериализация в форматах xml/json/binary